# Core Data search where dates are saved as NSStrings

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsstring, nsdate, nspredicate

I am working on creating a search mechanism where the user can specify which fields to search on, the operators to use and the values to search for. More like an advanced search. However, I also need to search for dates and date ranges but the problem is that dates are declared as NSStrings and not NSDates. So basically they are strings that represent dates (and not literally dates as I am referring to them as). An example of a string that represents a date in the database is: 2014-11-25T00:00:00+1000.

So, without changing the values and their respective fields to NSDates in a migration, is there a way to keep what we already have but instead specify a sort of conversion criteria for my predicate query so that Core Data can convert the NSString field values to NSDates and then do the comparison to determine weather a record fits into the specified criteria or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that CoreData can't convert `NSString`s into `NSDate`s for you, what you'll have to do is create a parsing algorithm that converts it for you. The format looks like it's an ISO8601 date format, which is used in web development, so I'm assuming you've downloaded this data from somewhere?

I've developed date parsing algorithms before and with proper testing you can build something quite robust, quite quickly. What you can do then is convert your `NSDate`'s into strings and then feed those strings into your fetch predicates.

Comment: the issue is not necessarily being able to convert NSStrings to NSDate or vice versa, its how I can have Core Data return some results that lie between a given date range for example where DOB >1990 and DOB <1995 where the DOBs where declared and saved as NSStrings. Im not sure if there is a solution that doesn't involve changing DOB to NSDate and then a migration.

Comment: The answer may be a property fetch of your entire database which you could then parse and fetch only the objects which fall in the desired date range. A property fetch is more efficient than fetching the entire object.

Comment: you are right RASS. I did some testing. It seems calling a category method to convert the strings to dates for comparison only works when filtering objects that have already been retrieved into an array. A fetch from the database is not possible with the custom filtering. And yes I will have to prefetch the fields that I want to use for the filtering. Maybe having them get fetched during the coma prison might work too, will do some tests